# 150 digits number multiplication in C

Tags: c

Here's the code that I have written -

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char numbr_1[150];
    char numbr_2[150];
    int ansr[22500];
    int i, j, d1, d2, n2, n1, ans, c, l1, l2, fl = 22500, temp1 = 0, temp2 = 0;
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter 1st number");
    gets(numbr_1);
    printf("Enter 2nd number");
    gets(numbr_2);

    l1 = strlen(numbr_1);
    l2 = strlen(numbr_2);

    for (i = 0; i < fl; i++)
        ansr[i] = 0;

    c = 0;

    for (i = l1 - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (j = l2 - 1; j >= 0; j--) {

            n1 = numbr_1[i] - 48;
            n2 = numbr_2[j] - 48;
            ans = n1 * n2;

            temp2 = fl - c - (l2 - j);
            ansr[temp2] += ans;
            while (ansr[temp2] > 9) {
                temp1 = ansr[temp2];
                ansr[temp2] = ansr[temp2] % 10;
                ansr[temp2 - 1] += temp1 / 10;
                temp2--;
            }
        }
        c++;
    }

    i = 0;

    while (ansr[i++] == 0);

    for (j = --i; j < fl; j++)
        printf("%d", ansr[j]);

    getch();
    return (1);
}
```

It works fine for answer less than 22500 digits, it even works for 22499 digits that is 149 digits number * 150 digits number
I just wanted to know is this some incapability or C or if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Could you format your code?

Comment: format ?? I didn't get you ???

Comment: I meant: use proper indentation to make it easier to read.

Comment: I could have sworn this said C++. Actually, `gets` is no longer C, nor C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is simple buffer overflow. You're reading in 150 character strings, but your string buffers are only 150 characters long - there's no room for the terminating null character.

Comment: @SHANTANUSINGH make your buffers 151 characters, or even larger if you want to be really safe. Make your output buffer larger too.

Comment: I am actually quite new with C, can you help with how to do that ... I tried google but it gives answer for only JAVA

Comment: @SHANTANUSINGH if you search for the number `150` in your code it should be obvious.